# Probability of discrete events

Tags: confidence-interval, dataset

An experiment has two possible outcomes: A or B.  In 20 experiments, A happened 2 times, and B happens 18 times. What would I expect from a larger number of experiments? With what confidence can I say that the mean number of outcome A is 10%?

Comment: Is this a homework problem? Also, what have you done so far to figure this out?

Comment: The question could be worded better since the sample is 10% and the confidence interval is about the population mean.

Comment: @Michael, the question is posed as a prediction interval, not a confidence interval.  Peter, the distinction I am making--and would appreciate your clarification on--is that questions phrased like this often ask for reasonable bounds, called "confidence limits," on the mean proportion of $A$ in a hypothetically *infinite* number of experiments. When you would like to bound the number of times $A$ will occur in a specified *finite* number of additional experiments, you are asking for a "prediction interval." It will differ (slightly) from the confidence interval.

Comment: @whuber I am not sure of that.  The question is incorrectly worded. I was taking my best guess at what was intended to be asked.

Comment: Rather than guessing (and attacking the question), please just ask the OP for clarification, @Michael.

Comment: @whuber I really don't think that this question has anything to do with prediction intervals.  I think the sentence "What would I expect from a large number of experiments?" is vague but may be trying to get at the fact that the sample estimate is approximately normal or that the width of the confidence intervals is going to 0.

Comment: I did mention to the OP that the question was poorly worded before I answered the question.  It does appear to be a homework problem.  In my answer I emphasized that the question was poorly worded and I told the OP what my interpretation is. Treating it as a homework problem I mentioned some important ideas and the approaches without going through the detailed calculations. My interpretation of the problem is very likely correct.  I don't see why we should waste time waiting for the OP to answer questions that me may or may not know how to jnterpret.

Comment: @whuber It is helpful that you point out an alternative interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is probably a homework problem and incorrectly worded, let me state the question intends to ask:

> Given A occurs 2 out of 20 times what would be a 95% confidence
> interval for p=P(A occurs on a given trial)?

The individual trials must be assumed to be independent Bernoulli trials.  Then the number of times A occurs has a binomial distribution.  You can use a normal approximation based on the central limit theorem or you can use the Clopper-Pearson method to get the exact binomial confidence interval for the parameter p.  The normal approximation may not be very good because the sample size is only 20.  So if you use the normal approximation you should use the continuity correction.  For the normal approximation keep in mind that the variance for the sample estimate of the proportion is p(1-p)/n.

Comment: Please go easy on the implicit condemnation of the question, Michael. If you think it is "incorrectly worded" then help the asker improve and clarify it, rather than jumping in with criticism and and answering what you *think* the question might be asking.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question as given

1) From a larger number of trials, you would expect 10% A and 90% B, assuming this is a random sample of trials.

2) You can say with 100% confidence that the mean number of A is 10% in this sample, and you can be quite sure that, in a large sample, it will *not* be exactly 10%. If the true probability is 10%, then, as N increases, the probability of getting exactly 10% in a sample goes down, but the probability of getting *about* 10% goes up. Indeed, you can only get exactly 10% A if N is a multiple of 10.

However, as others have pointed out, this may not be the question you intended to ask.